# TS2352: Conversion of type 'Extract<keyof T, string>' to type 'K' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other

Tags: typescript-typings

**I want to ignore some fields when the object is expanded**

```
How to modify compilation error report
```

```
function omit<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, keys: K[]): Omit<T, K> {
  const rest = {} as Omit<T, K>;
  for (const prop in obj) {
    if (!keys.includes(prop as K)) {
      rest[prop] = obj[prop];
    }
  }
  return rest;
}
```